Suddenly the text on my Quick Launch and the little arrow for ongoing processes got really small
I'm on a PC using W10 and Chrome.  Suddenly the text that says Quick Launch the quote marks where you click to launch it and the arrow next to these that you click to see the icons of the running processes just got SUPER small...  I don't know if I can include a picture here, but this has never happened before and I can't seem to find any threads about his anywhere.

Appreciate any help, thanks!
